# How to submit JForm form based on custom dropdown list value change

Tags: javascript, jform, dropdown

I'm working on a custom Joomla module. I have a JForm that contains multiple custom dropdown lists based on JFormFieldList. The form should be submitted when a value is selected from one of the custom lists.

What is the best way to do this? 
It seems that I should add the following expression to select html tag:
onchange="this.form.submit()

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231157/how-to-submit-form-on-change-of-dropdown-list

But as the html select tag is not directly generated by my code, I'm not sure how to do this the best.

Any hints are highly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Just to have this clearer: what is the purpose of submitting the form at every selection? I ask this since I answered this kind of questions earlier and it came out that it was not important to submit the form at every input, only the person who has asked the question have not understand before how jQuery ajax works on forms for example. So what’s the purpose here? Please give a bit more details about that.

Comment: There is a cascading relationship between list1 and list2, so the options in list2 will be narrowed down based on the selection in list1. In general I understand the concept of AJAX and partially reloading a page, but I have no experience in how this works for Joomla and PHP, so I wanted to implement a full page reload first quickly and maybe adding the ajax functionality later on when I have more time. If there is an easy and quick way to do this with AJAX that would be also perfect.

Comment: Thank you! Now it’s quite clear what you would like to have and why. Me or someone else here will be able to help you in this based on the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onchange` attribute can be added to the fields in your XML form. E.g. this is used in filter forms:

```
<field
    name="access"
    type="accesslevel"
    label="JOPTION_FILTER_ACCESS"
    description="JOPTION_FILTER_ACCESS_DESC"
    onchange="this.form.submit();"
    >
    <option value="">JOPTION_SELECT_ACCESS</option>
</field>
```

If your component follows Joomla's standard MVC pattern, you can use controller's `reload()` method to reload the form.

```
onchange="Joomla.submitform('example.reload', this.form)"
```

Where `example` is the name of the controller.

Comment: Wow, this is really simple and works like a charm! Thanks a lot! BTW: I don't think I saw any mentioning of an "onchange" attribute in the standard form field types documentation or anywhere else. What is the best way to learn about options like this?